# Create a fullchain bundle ssl cert from Komodo certs

Tags: ssl

I am trying to create a full-chan(bundle) cert, from the base certs provide by Komodo. I can get the certificate to work, but when I validate using www.ssllabs.com, it gives me this warning <

`chain issues: "Incorrect order, Extra certs, Contains anchor"`

These are the provided certs and the notes from Komodo:

```
# Root CA Certificate - AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
# Intermediate CA Certificate - USERTrustRSAAddTrustCA.crt
# Intermediate CA Certificate - GlobeSSLDVCA.crt
# Your Globe Standard Wildcard SSL Certificate - STAR_example_com.crt

tree .
├── certs
│   ├── AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
│   ├── GlobeSSLDVCA.crt
│   ├── STAR_example_com.crt
│   └── USERTrustRSAAddTrustCA.crt
```

And this is how I have created the bundle which gives me the error/warning:

```
cat certs/STAR_example_com.crt \
    certs/GlobeSSLDVCA.crt \
    certs/USERTrustRSAAddTrustCA.crt \
    certs/AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt \
    >> httpbin.example.com.crt
```

From the reading I have done it seems this is the correct process, but obviously not:

```
Domain cert
Intermediate cert 1 above domain
Intermediate cert 2 above that and so on
Root cert
```

Any help would be appreciated, as I am usually just provided with a full-chain to use.

Cheers in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All good I ended up working it out. But feel free to correct me if I am wrong. That pattern suggested was correct with the only difference being to exclude the "root" certificate from the "bundle". There is a bit of conflicting advice on this but, it now passes the ssl test with no warnings.

```
cat certs/STAR_example_com.crt \
    certs/GlobeSSLDVCA.crt \
    >> httpbin.example.com.crt
```